# STM32H747 MDMA Transfer Error Address when using FreeRTOS

Tags: stm32, spi, dma, freertos

I'm using the MDMA to communicate with an external flash over QUADSPI.

I have an implementation which works great without FreeRTOS, but when I implement it using FreeRTOS I get Transfer Error Address. I have verified that the RAM address exists in AXI memory so it seems like there is something about FreeRTOS that is not allowing the MDMA to read the memory?

```
// Write operation
MDMA_Channel0->CDAR = &QUADSPI->DR;
MDMA_Channel0->CSAR = pData;        // pData is a uint8_t*
 
// Read operation
MDMA_Channel0->CDAR = pData;
MDMA_Channel0->CSAR = &QUADSPI->DR;
```

I've seen the issue with both read and write operations. For both read and write the MDMA_CESR_TED = 0, meaning that the error is related to a read access.

This is the flow of the program:

1. [FreeRTOS task] Perform write operation, set volatile flag indicating flash operations are busy
2. [MDMA transfer complete interrupt] Disable MDMA
3. [SPI transfer complete interrupt] Start polling flash status with QUADSPI
4. [Polling match interrupt] set flag indicating flash operations are ready
5. [FreeRTOS task] Perform read operation, set volatile flag indicating flash operations are busy
6. **[MDMA Transfer Error Interrupt]**

These are the MDMA registers when I enable the MDMA at step 5:
[image]

These are the MDMA registers when I get the error interrupt at step 6:
[image]

These are the QUADSPI registers when I enable the MDMA at step 5:
[image]

These are the QUADSPI registers when I get the error interrupt at step 6:
[image]

I have tried adding various delays in case it is a timing issue but to no avail. I don't understand why I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that caused the error was

```
MDMA_CxTBR_SBUS
```

Changing that from 1 to 0, and it no longer crashed. The other issue I faced which is why I though this was RTOS related was that the FreeRTOS variables shared the same memory in RAM as my local variables.